# Given cell address as =Sheet1:A1, how to get the value

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2007

I have an address as =Sheet1:A1 or  =Sheet1:A1:B5 (Inputs)

It has some values. How can I get it using Excel VSTO and C#

Comment: That should be =Sheet1!A1 or =Sheet1!A1:B5 (`!` instead of `:`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I totally understand, but generally you don't need to use the sheet name prefix in VSTO. You do need a reference to the worksheet, however.  Kind of like this:

```
Excel.Worksheet ws;

//... get a reference to the worksheet

// you can get the value of a single cell into an object variable.
var rangeA1 = ws.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing);
var myValue = rangeA1.Value2;

// you can also pull out the value of a multicell range into a 2D array.
var rangeA1B5 = ws.get_Range("A1", "B5");
var myArrayOfValues = (object[,])rangeA1B5.Value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just parse the string:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

object _ = Type.Missing;
Excel.Workbook wb = ...; // get reference to workbook
string addr = "=Sheet1!A1:B5";
Match m = Regex.Match(addr, "^\=(?<sheet>[^!]+)!(?<cell>.+)$");
object value = wb.Worksheets[m.Groups["sheet"].Value].get_Range(m.Groups["cell"].Value, _).get_Value(_);
```

Might be missing a few casts.